# Concatenate strings while filtering by another column in SQL Server view

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

My table `SC` is of the following format:

```
Team        Owner
------------------
 A            1
 A            2
 B            3
 B            4
```

I would like my output in the **view** to be:

```
Team        Owners
-------------------
 A            1,2
 B            3,4
```

I tried using FOR XML PATH as follows in the view's design:

```
STUFF((SELECT ', ' + temp.Owner 
       FROM (SELECT SC.Owner) temp 
       WHERE (SC.Owner = temp.Owner) 
       FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'VARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 2, '') AS Owners
```

But it gives me an error, since this is a view's design and not a standard transaction:

> Error in WHERE clause near '('.
>   Unable to parse query text.`

Any suggestions on how to achieve what I would like?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code should look something like this:

```
select team,
       stuff((select ',' + sc2.owner
              from sc sc2
              where sc2.team = sc.team
              for xml path ('')
             ), 1, 1, '') as owners
from sc
group by team;
```

Answer (score 0):

What about:

```
SELECT team, GROUP_CONCAT(owner ORDER BY owner ASC SEPARATOR ',') as owners FROM sc GROUP BY team
```